# ¿Alteración del significado de la pregunta: Concatenar 2 String? Actualización2: Moderador alterando pregunta

Tags: discusión, pregunta-específica, títulos-de-preguntas

La [edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/65327/revisions) número 5 de la pregunta [Concatenar 2 String](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65327/android-concatenar-2-o-varias-variables-string)

¿Constituye una alteración de la pregunta que cambia su significado?

La pregunta claramente preguntaba por concatenar 2 cadenas. Y no preguntaba por concatenar varias. Esto es significativo porque la respuesta cambia si se trata de varias cadenas a manejar en un bucle.

Creo que es un abuso del privilego de edición. Pero no quiero entrar en una guerra de ediciones. Si veo que hay un acuerdo al respecto lo revertiré, aunque probablemente alguien lo haga antes.

## Actualización: guerra de ediciones

No ha sido posible evitar la guerra de ediciones. La edición 4 fue revertida tal y como se explica en la respuesta de fedorqui.
Pero la usuaria que hizo esa edición ha vuelto a rehacer esa edición (es la 9).
¿Qué hacer en este caso? Imagino que reportar y pedir que la pregunta se proteja contra ediciones.

## Actualización 2: Moderador alterando la pregunta

Pues no, reportarla no ha funcionado. Solo he conseguido que uno más se sume a la guerra de ediciones.
El moderador, Luigi Mendoza, ha deshecho la cita incorrecta a la que me refería anteriormente. Pero lamentablemente ha aprovechado para cambiar la pregunta de Android a Java además de cambiar las etiquetas (edición 10). Nótese que el título original de la pregunta era:

> Android: Sumar 2 String

¿Qué hacer ahora?

Comment: que sean varias tampco hace que necesite un bucle no ?

Comment: @lois6b No necesariamente. Pero abre la posibilidad. Como estaba antes la pregunta quedaba mucho más claro que esa posibilidad estaba cerrada. Adicionalmente antes el título de la pregunta y el cuerpo preguntaban lo mismo, ahora no.

Comment: Ohhh, en esa pregunta me crucificaron por el código de prueba que puse. Menos mal que no todos eran apologistas del benchmark y al menos evitaron que la misma tuviese votos en negativo. Yo la editaría poniendo en la pregunta en negritas: **si es posible mostrar un benchmark hecho con todas las normas vigentes**. Bueno, es broma.

Comment: Considero que un usuario puede acceder a la pregunta, tal vez solo busque concatenar 2 Strings o multiples, pero revisando la discusión tomaría la decisión de que usar, **consideré que es más útil**. En fin.

Comment: Hasta donde tengo entendido: Android es la plataforma y su lenguaje es Java si se trabaja tradicionalmente y se desconoce de Xamarin (C#). La concatenación de cadenas en esencia va a seguir igual si es 2 o más. Saludos :D

Comment: @Jorgesys entiendo que puede puede parecerte más útil. Sin embargo, habida cuenta que el tema se discutió aquí y consiguió bastante consenso (mi respuesta tiene +5 y -1), creo que no es pertinente que pases por encima de ese consenso para imponer tu sensación. En general, cuando un tema tiene diferentes puntos de vista es buena etiqueta discutirlo en Meta y proceder con el consenso que la comunidad decida. Si no, entramos en una guerra de ediciones muy poco productiva.

Comment: No sé qué tendrá de Android esa pregunta. Yo lo quitaría del título y la etiqueta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que no es pertinente el cambio de título y también creo bueno traer el debate aquí para evitar la guerra de ediciones.

Particularmente, desharía las revisiones 4 y 5 ([véanse todas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/65327/revisions)) puesto que la 4.ª añade un [bloque de citación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) a una simple pregunta y la 5.ª, esta que trajiste a colación aquí, añade un nivel de generalidad que puede provocar que algunas respuestas queden obsoletas innecesariamente.

¿Qué tal si se consulta con el autor de la pregunta antes de realizar estas modificaciones? Es loable perseguir preguntas útiles, pero también es bueno tener en consideración la finalidad de quien lo preguntaba.

<sub>En otro orden de cosas, me parece harto ridículo que toda pregunta de Java o Android acabe como el rosario de la aurora con votos negativos a diestro y siniestro... Si bien observo que hay debate productivo, me apena ver que se tiran los trastos a la cabeza y se lleven temas a lo personal. Contamos con una magnífica colección de gurús de Java, colaborando y debatiendo llegaréis mucho más lejos y con ello a la comunidad. **Mantener una comunidad sana es responsabilidad de todos**: si observáis comentarios no apropiados, ¡reportadlos! Ignorarlos no ayuda.</sub>

Comment: A mi también me gustaría que el diálogo fuese de otra manera. Yo he puesto 4 negativos a 4 respuestas que considero objetivamente incorrectas, todos ellos razonados. Y en los comentarios procuro limitarme a la cuestión técnica de la respuesta. Pienso que esos comentarios ayudarían a mejorar esas respuestas si se viesesen así en vez de verse como el ataque personal que no son. A todos les he votado positivo en otras ocasiones y en algunos casos he escrito haciendo ver lo correcto de esas otras respuestas suyas. Es cierto que tanto comentario acaba convirtiéndose en ruido.

Comment: Tentado estoy de borrar todos mis comentarios en esa pregunta. ¿Tu qué harías en mi caso fedorqui? Seguiré tu consejo.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos suelen decir que los comentarios son elementos de segunda categoría en estos sitios. Por tanto, todo aquello que quieras conservar es mejor moverlo a las publicaciones. El resto, si ves que no contribuye a que la persona implicada reflexione, puedes eliminarlo. Mi experiencia en [se] me indica que si alguien no está de acuerdo con otro y lo expresa en un comentario, ulteriores comentarios solamente acrecentarán la diferencia y rápidamente tocarán egos personales. Pero vaya, todo va a gustos :)

Comment: Yo opino que los mantengas, además proporcionas información extra con los links a wikipedia....

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos nótese que Jorgesys te contestó ahora mismo ^^^